# Strange problem with diagrams: can't convert correctly

Tags: anki

I have an odd problem - not really with the diagrams package, but it starts there, in a sense - can anybody spot what I am doing wrong? Or what I should do to get around it?

This is what I am trying to do:

I am making notes in texStudio following Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context", using Paul Taylor's commutative diagrams package; this works very well.

I am also, now, extracting all the definitions as flash-cards to be imported into AnkiDroid 2.1 - this also works well, except for when the arrows in the diagrams are diagonal. I have been able to narrow the problem down to the conversion to .png, that AnkiDroid requires; the same happens whether I use:

```
dvipng -D 200 -T tight test.dvi -o test2.png
```

or

```
convert -density 200 -trim test.pdf test.png
```

---

This is the code:

```
% -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\usepackage{diagrams}

\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}

\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{obs}{Observe}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{exe}{Exercises}[section]

\newcommand{\lift}[2]{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
    \put(0,{#1}){\makebox(0,0)[b]{${#2}$}}
    \end{picture}
}

\newcommand{\lowerarrow}[1]{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.03\DiagramCellWidth}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
    \qbezier(-28,-4)(0,-18)(28,-4)
    \put(0,-14){\makebox(0,0)[t]{$\scriptstyle {#1}$}}
    \put(28.6,-3.7){\vector(2,1){0}}
    \end{picture}
}

\newcommand{\upperarrow}[1]{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.03\DiagramCellWidth}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
    \qbezier(-28,11)(0,25)(28,11)
    \put(0,21){\makebox(0,0)[b]{$\scriptstyle {#1}$}}
    \put(28.6,10.7){\vector(2,-1){0}}
    \end{picture}
}

\newenvironment{note}{\paragraph{NOTE:}}{}
\newenvironment{field}{\paragraph{field:}}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{note}
        \begin{field}
            \textbf{Slice categories}
        \end{field}
        \begin{field}
            \begin{enumerate}[i]
                \item $c/C$, called \textbf{C under c}, is the category whose objects are morphisms $f \colon c \rightarrow x$ with domain $c$ and in which a morphism from $f \colon c \rightarrow x$ to $g \colon c \rightarrow y$ is a map $h \colon x \rightarrow y$ between the codomains so that the triangle:
                \begin{diagram} \label{DiagramCunderc}
                    & & c & & \\
                    & \ldTo^f & & \rdTo^g & \\
                    x & & \rTo^h & & y
                \end{diagram}
                \textbf{commutes}, i.e., so that g = h f .
                \item $C/c$, called \textbf{C over c}, is the category whose objects are morphisms $f \colon x \rightarrow c$ with codomain $c$ and in which a morphism from $f \colon x \rightarrow c$ to $g \colon y \rightarrow c$ is a map $h \colon x \rightarrow y$ between the domains so that the triangle:
                \begin{diagram} \label{DiagramCoverc}
                    x & & \rTo^h & & y \\
                    & \rdTo_f & & \ldTo_g & \\
                    & & c & &
                \end{diagram}
                \textbf{commutes}, i.e. so that $f = g h$.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{field}
        \begin{field}
            Category
        \end{field}
    \end{note}
\end{document}
```

This is what it should look like (this is a screenshot of the PDF file generated - it looks identical to the DVI I also generated):

[image]

But this is what it ends up as:

[image]

Comment: Do you absolutely want to use `diagrams`? Other packages do a very good job (`pstricks`,  tikz-cd`).

Comment: Absolutely? I suppose not, but it is what I know, so I would like to be persuaded before I use something else. Also, I feel that is a bit irrelevant in this case - it ought to be possible to convert the PDF to PNG regardless of how it was created, although I realise this may not be the case in practice.

Comment: Do the input files (dvi and pdf) represent the diagonals correctly?

Comment: @StefanSchroeder: Yes, thanks for reminding me - I should have mentioned this in the original question. Yes, it is represented correctly.

Comment: Here you will find a couple of different approaches how to convert pdf to png; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653380/converting-a-pdf-to-png

Answer (score 0):

Here  is how to obtain these diagrams with `pstricks`, if it can be useful:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbold}

\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}

\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{obs}{Observe}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{exe}{Exercises}[section]

\newenvironment{note}{\paragraph{NOTE:}}{}
\newenvironment{field}{\paragraph{field:}}{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{note}
        \begin{field}
            \textbf{Slice categories}
        \end{field}
        \begin{field}
            \begin{enumerate}[i]
                \item $c/C$, called \textbf{C under c}, is the category whose objects are morphisms $f \colon c \rightarrow x$ with domain $c$ and in which a morphism from $f \colon c \rightarrow x$ to $g \colon c \rightarrow y$ is a map $h \colon x \rightarrow y$ between the codomains so that the triangle:
                    \begin{postscript} \[
                    \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesepA=3pt, nodesepB=2pt, labelsep=2pt, shortput=nab, linejoin=1}
                    \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
                      \begin{psmatrix}
                         & [name=c] c \\
                       [name=x] x & & [name=y] y
                    \ncline{x}{y}^{h}
                    \ncline{c}{x}\nbput[nrot=:D]{f}
                    \ncline{c}{y}\naput[nrot=:U]{g}
                      \end{psmatrix}
                    \] \end{postscript}
                \textbf{commutes}, i.e., so that $ g = h f $.
                \item $C/c$, called \textbf{C over c}, is the category whose objects are morphisms $f \colon x \rightarrow c$ with codomain $c$ and in which a morphism from $f \colon x \rightarrow c$ to $g \colon y \rightarrow c$ is a map $h \colon x \rightarrow y$ between the domains so that the triangle:
                    \begin{postscript} \[
                    \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesepA=3pt, nodesepB=2pt, labelsep=3pt, shortput=nab}
                    \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
                      \begin{psmatrix}
                       [name=x] x & & [name=y] y \\
                         & [name=c] c
                    \ncline{x}{y}^{h}
                    \ncline{x}{c}\nbput[nrot=:U]{f}
                    \ncline{y}{c}\naput[nrot=:D]{g}
                      \end{psmatrix}
                    \] \end{postscript}
                \textbf{commutes}, i.e. so that $f = g h$.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{field}
        \begin{field}
            Category
        \end{field}
    \end{note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your update - I'm still experimenting with different options, and the problem I have now is that I can't see the intermediary files that are generated by the import into Anki. I have got it to work from the command line, so apparently the import doesn't do quite what I think it does. I'll get back when I have resolved the problem - others might have the same sort of trouble.